# why do I keep getting missing link errors with my email activation

Tags: php

I have done an email activation,  which is working but am trying to adopt the same concept for my antispam activation. It is working for some people but sometimes, I keep getting that one of the variables is not set, is just just a trial and error thing?

I also read somewhere that I should include a not empty check too after the **isset()** check.

```
<?php
include_once __DIR__.'/header2.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../header2.php?reply=mustloggedoutfirst'>"; 
    exit();
} else {
if(!isset($_GET['email']) && $_GET['email'] !== '' || !isset($_GET['userid']) && $_GET['userid'] !== '' || !isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '' || !isset($_GET['reply_registration_expirydate']) && $_GET['reply_registration_expirydate'] !== '') {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../index.php?reply=missinglink'>"; 
    exit();
} else {
    $email = strip_tags($_GET['email']);
    $username = strip_tags($_GET['userid']);
    $id = strip_tags($_GET['id']);
    $reply_registration_expirydate = strip_tags($_GET['reply_registration_expirydate']);

    if (empty($_SESSION['key'])) {
        $_SESSION['key'] = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
      }

}
}
```

I forgot to add to my previous question that initially, I had the following code, which seems to work for most people for not for some...

```
if (!isset($_GET['email']) || !isset($_GET['activatetoken']) || !isset($_GET['reply_registration_expirydate'])) { 
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../index.php?reply=missinglink'>"; 
    exit();
```

Comment: what is thie code supposed to do other than set the session var `key` if no errors are detected? Is there code that follows this based upon that session variable?

Answer (score 0):

Update your IF-clause and remove the negation of "isset".

With "!isset($_GET['email']) && $_GET['email'] !== ''" you're checking if the variable is NOT set and then (being not set) if it's NOT unequal to an empty string, this must run into a "variable not set"-error.

Comment: apologies... then I think it should be if the variable is not set and empty

Comment: $email = strip_tags($_GET['email']);
    $username = strip_tags($_GET['userid']);
    $id = strip_tags($_GET['id']);
    $reply_registration_expirydate = strip_tags($_GET['reply_registration_expirydate']);

Comment: do I need to use strip_tags here and is it okay to use it here?

Comment: As I said: remove the negation. If it's not set, there's no need to check whether it's empty. strip_tags has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

The logical order of your if statement is probably incorrect. By "missing link errors" you probably mean this part of the if-statement is executed:

```
if(!isset($_GET['email']) && $_GET['email'] !== '' || !isset($_GET['userid']) && $_GET['userid'] !== '' || !isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '' || !isset($_GET['reply_registration_expirydate']) && $_GET['reply_registration_expirydate'] !== '') {
```

formatted:

```
if (! isset($_GET['email'])                             //        IS NOT SET email
  && $_GET['email'] !== ''                              // and    IS NOT EMPTY email
  || !isset($_GET['userid'])                            // or     IS NOT SET userid
  && $_GET['userid'] !== ''                             // and    IS NOT EMPTY userid
  || !isset($_GET['id'])                                // or     IS NOT SET id
  && $_GET['id'] !== ''                                 // and    IS NOT EMPTY id
  || !isset($_GET['reply_registration_expirydate'])     // or     IS NOT SET reply_registration_expirydate
  && $_GET['reply_registration_expirydate'] !== '') {   // and    IS NOT EMPTY reply_registration_expirydate
```

Due to the [precedence of the operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), your statement might evaluate to true earlier than you want. You need to use parentheses to group operands.

```
if ((! isset($_GET['email'])                             //        (IS NOT SET email
  && $_GET['email'] !== '')                              // and    IS NOT EMPTY email)
  || (!isset($_GET['userid'])                            // or     (IS NOT SET userid
  && $_GET['userid'] !== '')                             // and    IS NOT EMPTY userid)
  || (!isset($_GET['id'])                                // or     (IS NOT SET id
  && $_GET['id'] !== '')                                 // and    IS NOT EMPTY id)
  || (!isset($_GET['reply_registration_expirydate'])     // or     (IS NOT SET reply_registration_expirydate
  && $_GET['reply_registration_expirydate'] !== '')) {   // and    IS NOT EMPTY reply_registration_expirydate)
```